Sequence converges, then the mean also converges (withouht knowing the mean converges to the same value)
Maybe this question has been read a lot of timehere but I failed to find this kind of version. Let me explain.

Let  $\{a_n\}$ be a convergent sequence, then $\left \{ \frac{S_n}{n} \right\}$ also converges, where $S_n = a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$.

It is well known that the mean of a convergent sequence also converges to the same value as the sequence, and all the proofs that I find about this start with that assumption.
I just want to know if my arguments are correct. If anyone finds any errors, please just give me hints so I can try to find them myself.


PROOF
WLOG: Suppose $\{a_n\}\to 0$.
By contradiction, suppose $\left \{ \frac{S_n}{n} \right\}$ diverges, i.e:
$$
\text{For every }L, \exists\ \varepsilon > 0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }  \varepsilon \leq\left|\frac{S_n}{n} -L \right|\ , \forall n \geq N
$$
Let $L=0$, then exists $\varepsilon_1>0$ for every $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varepsilon_1 \leq\left|\frac{S_n}{n} \right|$.
Then, $$\varepsilon_1 \leq\left|\frac{S_n}{n} \right|=\left|\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n} \right|\leq \frac{|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|}{n} = (\star)$$
Since $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$, for $\varepsilon_2>0$ there exists $N_2 \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_m|<\varepsilon_2$ for all $m\geq N_2$. Take $(\star)$ and split the expression as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(a_1+\cdots+a_{N_2-1}+ a_{N_2}+a_{N_2+1}+ \cdots + a_n\right) = (\dagger) $$
The first $N'-1$ terms inside the parenthesis can be bounded by some $M$ since there are a finite amount of terms. The other terms are bounded because of the $\{a_n\}$. Then
$$
(\dagger) < \frac{M(N_2-1)}{n} + \frac{(n-N_2+1)}{n}\varepsilon_2
$$
We just need to pick some particular values:
$$\text{Set } \varepsilon_2 =\frac{n}{n-N_2+1} \frac{\varepsilon_1}{2}\\
\text{Pick } N' > N_2 \text{ such that } \frac{M(N_2-1)}{n} \leq \frac{\varepsilon_1}{2}, \ \forall n \geq N'.
$$
Finally, $$\varepsilon_1 \leq\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|< \frac{\varepsilon_1}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon_1}{2} = \varepsilon_1\quad (!)$$
Since we lead to a contradiction, our statement must to be true.
Hence, $\left \{ \frac{S_n}{n} \right\}$ converges. $\blacksquare$
EDIT:
After writing this, I think its the same technique as other proofs (lol). However, I've couldn't find a rigorous technique with epsilon arguments.

You might want to google the keyword Cesàro mean, or more generally, Stolz–Cesàro theorem.

I didn't know about this theorem. In fact, it is faster and does not struggle with epsilon-delta arguments.

Here's the way I
like to write it.
Of course
it is equivalent
to the others.
Suppose
$x_n \to a$.
Then,
for any $c > 0$,
there is a $N(c)$ such that
for all $n > N(c)$
we have
$|x_n-a| < c$.
Let
$y_n
=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}
$.
We now,
for any $c > 0$,
split the sum into two parts:
the "good" part where
$x_n$ is close to $a$,
and the "bad" part
where $x_n$ is
not close to $a$.
$\begin{array}\\
y_n-a
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}-a\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} x_k+\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n x_k}{n}-a\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)+aN(c)+\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n x_k}{n}-a\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}+\dfrac{aN(c)+\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n x_k}{n}-a\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}+\dfrac{aN(c)+\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n x_k-an}{n}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}+\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n (x_k-a)}{n}\\
\text{so}\\
|y_n-a|
&=\big| \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}+\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n (x_k-a)}{n}\big|\\
&\le \big| \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}\big|+\big|\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n (x_k-a)}{n}\big|\\
&\le \big| \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}\big|+\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n \big|x_k-a\big|}{n}\\
&\lt \big| \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}\big|+\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(c)+1}^n c}{n}\\
&= \big| \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}\big|+\dfrac{c(n-N(c))}{n}\\
&\le \big| \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(c)} (x_k-a)}{n}\big|+c\\
\end{array}
$
Let
$m(j)
=\max(|x_k-a|)_{k=1}^j 
$.
Then
$|y_n-a|
\le \dfrac{N(c)m(N(c))}{n}+c
$.
Finally,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
let
$c
=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$
and choose $n$ so that
$\dfrac{N(c)m(N(c))}{n} 
\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$,
i.e.,
$n 
\gt \dfrac{2N(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2})m(N(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}))}{\epsilon}
$
and
$n > N(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2})$.
Therefore,
if
$n > \max(N(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}), \dfrac{2N(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2})m(N(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}))}{\epsilon})$,
$|y_n-a| < \epsilon|$
so $y_n \to a$.
